# VBA/Excel Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

Getting an Application-defined or object-defined error in my excel vba macro and I'm not sure why.  I'm guessing it has something to do with how I am calling the cell reference.  I've looked at some of the other similar questions to this.  They are very similar, but I am missing it where my mistake is.

Here's the code:

```
Set AllianceSheet = Worksheets(2)

Dim YearBeginRange As Range
Dim YearEndRange As Range
Dim Year As Integer
Dim BeginRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim CountryRange As Range
'Dim WS As Worksheet
'Dim WSName As String

Year = 1965
'WSName = "Ally-" & Year



Set YearBeginRange = AllianceSheet.Range("C1", AllianceSheet.Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Find(What:=Year, After:=AllianceSheet.Range("C1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If YearBeginRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Year & "Begin year not found"
    Else
        'MsgBox Year & "Begin year found!"
        'Debug.Print YearBeginRange.Row
        'Debug.Print TypeName(YearBeginRange.Row)
        BeginRow = YearBeginRange.Row
    End If

Set YearEndRange = AllianceSheet.Range("C1", AllianceSheet.Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Find(What:=Year + 1, After:=AllianceSheet.Range("C1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If YearBeginRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Year & "End year not found"
    Else
        EndRow = YearEndRange.Row
    End If


Set CountryRange = AllianceSheet.Range(AllianceSheet.Cells(1, BeginRow), AllianceSheet.Cells(1, EndRow))



'Debug.Print BeginRow
'Debug.Print EndRow
'Debug.Print WSName

End Sub
```

The error comes at the:

```
Set CountryRange = AllianceSheet.Range(AllianceSheet.Cells(1, BeginRow), AllianceSheet.Cells(1, EndRow))
```

I know I'm missing something very basic so thanks in advance.  FYI, BeginRow= 65930 and EndRow = 81430 in this case.

Comment: EndRow is nothing if YearEndRange is not found.  Where you search (.Find) for YearEndRange, you test for YearBeginRange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments to `.Cells` reversed - it should be `row, column`, not `column, row`:

```
Set CountryRange = AllianceSheet.Range(AllianceSheet.Cells(BeginRow, 1), _
                                       AllianceSheet.Cells(EndRow, 1))
```

Comment: @agnuke Most likely this is the Answer since the maximum number of columns a sheet can have is 16384 (office 2010), you can check by `Columns.Count`

Comment: Without even trying your correction, I'm going to go ahead and assume that you are correct and I am an idiot.  Thanks!